# What does the Vref pin do on the A5973D?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, voltage-reference

I'm thinking about using this switching regulator A5973D.

The data sheet is here:
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/98/04/af/4b/8c/a3/42/cc/CD00172501.pdf/files/CD00172501.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00172501.pdf

Does the Vref pin provide 3v3 or does it need to be connected to an external 3v3 supply?

My application includes a 3v3 MCU circuit and three A5973D circuits, one set to 3v3, one 5v and one 12v. What should I do with the Vref pins on each IC?

Comment: "Reference" page 7 : it's a 3.3V output. Safe to use up to 5mA current from it. Also safe to ignore if you don't need it. Also, confirmed on Page 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an output, a basically a linear regulator from the input voltage. You can only draw a few mA from it.

[image]

One possible use would be to have an always-powered low power circuit running from the 'reference' that would turn the switching regulator on and off.

Comment: So in my application in my above question I can just ignore the Vref pins?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can just leave the pin open if it's not useful in your design.

Answer (score 1):

It provides 3.3V out from a linear regulator that powers the internal circuit. It could be useful if you want to test or debug your circuit. You can monitor this voltage to determine if the chip is getting enough power internally.

Answer (score 0):

Vref provides 3.3V at up to 5mA. See the datasheet page 7.
[image]